# Infimum and Supremum of a set

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have to find infimum  and supremum of $$a+2Re(\delta z+\sigma z^2) $$
where $\delta, \sigma \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z\in \mathbb{D}$. Here $\mathbb{D}$ is disk of radius 1.

This may be very easy question but I don't get it. If you know then please give me some idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't the supremum and infimum be $\pm\infty$, respectively? Consider $z$ to be any real number of norm $\leq 1$, and let $\delta = 0$. Then, let $\sigma$ range over the real line.

Comment: Unless you mean for $\delta$ and $\sigma$ to be fixed, in which case, you should specify that.

Comment: @Michael, it for fixed $\delta$ and $ \sigma$

Comment: Okay, then the notation you want is $\inf_{z\in \mathbb{D}} (a+2\Re(\delta z+\sigma z^2))$. Otherwise it's not clear which quantities are variable and which are fixed. Ditto for $\sup$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $a \in \mathbb R$ and that $a, \delta$ and $ \sigma$ are fixed.

Then define $f(z)=a+\delta z +\sigma z^2$ and $u(z)=Re(f(z))=a+2Re(\delta z+\sigma z^2)$.

Since $f$ is holomorphic, $u$ is harmonic. By the min/max - principle we get

$ \inf u(\mathbb D)=\min u( \partial \mathbb D)$  and $ \sup u(\mathbb D)=\max u( \partial \mathbb D)$.

Can you procced ?

Comment: @ Fred, is it true sup occurs at z=1?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't proceed ahead. Could you please do it further. Thanks

Comment: Hint: for $z\in \partial\mathbb{D}$, i.e. $\lvert z\rvert = 1$, $z = e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ for some $\theta\in [0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: @MichaelLee, I tried by changing to polar cordinates, but $\delta$ and $\sigma$ both are complex number. How to deal with those. Just say me the real part of that function. Thanks

Comment: After putting $z=e^{i\theta}$, $u(z)=a+2re(\delta e^{i\theta}+\sigma e^{2i\theta})$. Then I supposed $\delta=b+ic$ and $\sigma=d+ie$. Therefore $u= a+2(b\cos\theta -c\sin\theta+d\cos2\theta-e\sin2\theta$. Now how to find min and max.

Comment: @MichaelLee I am still waiting for ur respond

Comment: Take the derivative with respect to $\theta$. The max and min will occur at points where it equals $0$. Use the double-angle formulas and the Pythagorean identity to get a polynomial in one trigonometric function.

Comment: @MichaelLee, The problem is I am not able to solve for $\theta$. There are four terms with single angle and double angle. How could we change to single trig function even if we use double angle and Pythagoream identity. I tried so hard but I didn't

Comment: @MichaelLee  , I tried every possible ways. Could you please solve for me. I'm tried of doing same stuff repeatedly.